# What is supposed to happen in ResultSet#next with the cursor on the insert row?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I'm a bit at a loss here. I'm supposed to write an implementation of `javax.sql.RowSet` for a specific purpose and I'm trying to unit-test it as well as far as I can.

Now, a `ResultSet` has a cursor that can be on a normal row (or before the first or after the last) or on the insert row. `moveToInsertRow()` says:

> Only the updater, getter, and insertRow methods may be called when the cursor is on the insert row.

Nothing is said on what is supposed to happen then. `next()` is less helpful by not even pointing that case out:

> Moves the cursor forward (sic!) one row from its current position. A `ResultSet` cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.
>
> When a call to the next method returns `false`, the cursor is positioned after the last row. Any invocation of a `ResultSet` method which requires a current row will result in a `SQLException` being thrown. If the result set type is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, it is vendor specified whether their JDBC driver implementation will return `false` or throw an `SQLException` on a subsequent call to `next`.
>
> If an input stream is open for the current row, a call to the method `next` will implicitly close it. A `ResultSet` object's warning chain is cleared when a new row is read.
>
> **Returns:**
> `true` if the new current row is valid; `false` if there are no more rows
>
> **Throws:**
> `SQLException` - if a database access error occurs or this method is called on a closed result set

I have no prior experience with the JDBC APIs and therefore have no clue whether that's intentionally unspecified (undefined behavior maybe?) or just an oversight.

Currently I think I'd just throw an `SQLException` even though that's nowhere specified and thus maybe `UnsupportedOperationException` would be better (as `SQLException` signals a DB error or a closed `ResultSet` – neither of which would be the case here).

Or did I just miss a bit of documentation somewhere?

Comment: That self same documentation made my head spin. So let's say you load 100 rows. 1) If you call next() on the Resultset, what are they talking about when they say an 'input stream'? 2) Can you call absolute(-1) again on the same ResultSet afterwards without getting an SQLException? 3) What's this 'warning chain'?

Comment: @JGFMK: 1. An input stream is an `InputStream` object passed in with one of the `update*Stream` methods, which can still be open. 2. `absolute(-1)` sounds weird, right now and I don't have the docs handy but I think it should be an error as there is no “minus first” row. 3. The warning chain collects warnings encountered by the database when calling various methods. It was unused in my implementation (as a CSV file won't create warnings) so I didn't care too much. You should be able to figure it out eventually, but the 200+ methods of `RowSet` don't make this easy.

Comment: absolute(-1) would position on last row. relative(-1) is same as previous() http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#relative(int)

Comment: @JGFMK: Ah, sorry, then. Forgot that.

Comment: A downvote. How cute. Any reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you follow the contract of `moveToInsertRow()` and throw some sort of exception (`SQL-` or `IllegalState-`). This is going to cause the least trouble if people mistakenly call `next()`.

You could also have a look at others' implementation to see what they do (MySQL Connector/J for example) so that other frameworks you use won't get surprised.

Comment: @Joey - As you point out, the API is undefined. You can choose what you want to do. As I said, it makes most sense to throw an exception. You could also look at what others do so as to not surprise other frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

How about just writing a small program to actually test the behavior of `next()` after `moveToInsertRow()`?

I'm a TDDer but sometimes when I'm programming something that uses a "foreign" API I would create a small proof of concept that is not really test driven, usually called a "spike", that way I can learn how the different API calls interact. 
When I feel like I have a good grasp of the API I just throw the spike away and start coding in normal TDD fashion.